# How to add product into the cart according to the stock in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuejs3

I am trying to add the products into my cart but only if the amount is less than stock. So when I click add to cart button I am getting an object like this:

[image]

So the amount is getting by the user. But I don't want to add the product into the cart if the stock is smaller than amount.

For this my cartHelper:

```
getCart: function (callback = undefined) {
        return apiHelper.getRequest(
            "/carts",
            (response) => {
                document.cookie = `${this.cartCookieName}=${response.data.attributes.cart_guid};`;
                this.cookieValue = response.data.attributes.cart_guid;
                if (callback) { callback(response); }
            }
        )
    },

    addToCart: function (product, variation_id, amount, callback = undefined) {
        if(this.cookieValue == "") {
            this.getCart(() => {
                this._addToCart(product, variation_id, amount, callback);
            });
        } else {
            this._addToCart(product, variation_id, amount, callback)
        }
    },

    _addToCart(product, variation_id, amount, callback = undefined) {
        return apiHelper.postRequest(
            `/carts/${this.cookieValue}/add-item`,
            (response) => {
                document.cookie = `${this.cartCookieName}=${response.data.attributes.cart_guid};`;
                if (callback) { callback(response); }
            },
            {
                product_id: product,
                variation_id: variation_id,
                amount: amount,
            }
        )
    },
```

I am calling the cart here and storing the id in cookie. According to that id I am making anouther call with body to put the product into the cart.
To put the product into the cart I am also using Vuex and here is my mutations:

```
export const ADD_TO_CART = (state, {product, variation, amount}) => {
    let productInCart = state.cart.find(item => {
        return item.product.id === product.id;
    });
    if(productInCart) {
        productInCart.amount += amount;
        return;
    }
    state.cart.push({
        product,
        variation,
        amount
    })
}
```

and here is my addToCart function in Product component:

```
addToCart: function () {
            let amount = this.itemsCount !== "" ? this.itemsCount : 1;
            if(this.variationId != null) {
                this.warningMessage = false;
                cartHelper.addToCart(this.product.id, this.variationId, amount, (response) => {
                    this.$store.dispatch('addProductToCart', {
                        product: this.product,
                        variation: this.variationId,
                        amount: parseInt(amount)
                    })
                });
            } else {
                this.warningMessage = true;
            }

        },
```

I am really confused about where should I make the check if the stock is enough, the product can be added to the cart. If you can help me with this, I would be really glad.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the mutation's `product` argument contains the stock count, so you could perform the check in the mutation:

```js
export const ADD_TO_CART = (state, {product, variation, amount}) => {
    if (amount > product.attributes.stock) {
      return
    }
    ⋮
    // add to cart
}
```

Or you could do it in the `Product` component before dispatching:

```js
export default {
    methods: {
        addToCart: function () {
            let amount = this.itemsCount !== "" ? this.itemsCount : 1;
            if (amount > this.product.attributes.stock) {
                return;
            }
            ⋮
            // dispatch action
        },
    }
}
```